# java_home still pointing to the latest version of java after launching jenv

Tags: java, macos, maven, homebrew

I have installed several versions of the JDK with brew cask:

```
MacBook-Pro:bin myusername$ brew cask list
java                                                        java8                                                       soapui
```

And set the default one to be java8:

```
MacBook-Pro:bin myusername$ jenv global
1.8.0.162
```

but when I lanuch maven it does not found `$JAVA_HOME` and fallbacks to using `java_home`:

```
MacBook-Pro:bin myusername$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The maven script:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME:-$(/usr/libexec/java_home)}" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.2/3.2.5/libexec/bin/mvn" "$@"
```

I could change the `mvn` script but if I can fix the `JAVA_HOME` issue it would be really much better. Any hints?

Answer (score 4):

For this you have to enable the jenv maven plugin. From the [documentation](https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv#plugins):

> Let's say you want Maven to use the JDK activated with Jenv, not the >default JAVA_HOME configuration. You need to activate Jenv's maven plugin.

```
$ jenv enable-plugin maven
maven plugin activated
```

> Note: The enable-plugin functionality is system wide not local to the shell, or temporary - you only need to do each one once.

Comment: Actually the problem was that `JAVA_HOME` was not set. To do it I've added the following to my `.bash_profile`: `export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/\`jenv version-name\` `

Comment: Yes, but with this you cannot switch between JVMs during a single session.

Comment: Perhaps an editor can change the title to highlight that this problem is maven-specific, I would have found this answer faster :-P

Answer (score 0):

Make sure maven is not using this file to set JAVA_HOME

~/.mavenrc

If so, delete it and make sure that java_home is set elsewhere (either using jenv or explicitly setting JAVA_HOME as per your need.